# Why do palpitations happen when someone is nearing something rewarding?

Tags: endocrinology, neurology

When you are nearing something rewarding (IE: winning a prize, or winning a game), why do you experience tachycardia?

For example, if someone entered a raffle with the number 9284938, and the announcer was starting to announce 9..2..8..4, the closer the announcer gets when palpations would start to occur.

My guess this is something to do with dopamine since dopamine is a rewarding hormone and it gets metabolized directly into epinephrine, but I don't think I'm right.

Comment: Palpitations (irregular, extra heart beats) are different from tachycardia (an increased heart rate often accompanying excitement/fear, etc. It's cause is norepinephrine (also known as adrenaline in some countries.) There may also be dopamine in there somewhere, but the major effect is the rush you get from adrenal release of nor-epi.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Thanks! I edited the question.